# Count occurences from one table based on different dates from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. First table has user id and period start and end dates (different for each user)

```
user_id |  start                       |  end
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       |  2019-07-02 13:30:14.103212  |  2021-07-02 13:30:14.103212
2       |  2020-06-27 07:39:30.333681  |  2021-07-02 13:30:14.103212
3       |  2020-06-16 08:30:58.287101  |  2021-07-02 13:30:14.103212
4       |  2020-06-27 19:21:28.014040  |  2021-07-02 13:30:14.103212
5       |  2020-05-28 11:23:15.814459  |  2021-07-02 13:30:14.103212
```

Second table has same user id and login dates, something like this:

```
user_id |  login_time                  |  
----------------------------------------
1       |  2019-07-02 13:30:14.103212  |
2       |  2020-06-27 07:39:30.333681  |
3       |  2020-06-16 08:30:58.287101  |
4       |  2020-06-27 19:21:28.014040  |
5       |  2020-05-28 11:23:15.814459  |
1       |  2019-07-02 13:30:14.103212  |
2       |  2020-06-27 07:39:30.333681  |
3       |  2020-06-16 08:30:58.287101  |
4       |  2020-06-27 19:21:28.014040  |
5       |  2020-05-28 11:23:15.814459  |
1       |  2019-07-02 13:30:14.103212  |
2       |  2020-06-27 07:39:30.333681  |
3       |  2020-06-16 08:30:58.287101  |
4       |  2020-06-27 19:21:28.014040  |
5       |  2020-05-28 11:23:15.814459  |
```

How can I count numbers each user has logged in in his specific time period from table1 (grouped by user_id) for all users in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.user_id
    ,t2.count(*)
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t2.login_time BETWEEN start AND END
GROUP BY t2.user_id
```